# eoslime test not saving data in table

Tags: smart-contract, nodeos, multi-index, unit-tests

This is my first experience with **eoslime** as I want to do unit testing for smart contracts. Not much experienced with **nodejs** .I am following eoslime documentation: https://docs.eoslime.limechain.tech/examples

I added *user smart contract* file in eoslime contracts directory. `eoslime compile` and `eoslime deploy` commands are going okay. eoslime `nodeos` is running. Following is my test file:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const TOKEN_WASM_PATH = './contracts/user/user.wasm';
const TOKEN_ABI_PATH = './contracts/user/user.abi';

describe("EOSIO User", function (eoslime) {

    // Increase mocha(testing framework) time, otherwise tests fails
    this.timeout(15000);

    let userContract;
        let userTable;
        let adminAccount;

    before(async () => {

            adminAccount = await eoslime.Account.load('accname','PK');
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {

        userContract = await eoslime.Contract.deploy(TOKEN_WASM_PATH, TOKEN_ABI_PATH);
        userTable = userContract.users;
    });

    it("Should create a new user", async () => {
             await userContract.upsertuser("123","123","123","123","123","123",1, ["grp1"], { from: adminAccount.name });
    });

    it("Should check user", async () => {

        let messages = await userTable.limit(10).find();
        messages = await userTable.equal(adminAccount.name).find();
        assert.equal(messages.length, 0, "Should not have any rows yet");
        const message = messages[0];
        assert.equal(message.created_by, adminAccount.name, "account name not correct");

    });

    it("Should remove user", async () => {
            await userContract.eraseuser("123", { from: adminAccount.name });
    });


});
```

Here, `upsertuser` is the action name which inserts data in multi-index table. While testing it does not give any error. The error is getting generated by `it("Should check user", async () => {` and `it("Should remove user", async () => {` because the data is not getting saved in table. The `abi` file contains this table:

```
"tables": [
        {
            "name": "users",
            "type": "usertable",
            "index_type": "i64",
            "key_names": [],
            "key_types": []
        }
    ]
```

Can anybody help, where I am mistaken? And how to check table data and transactions on chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is coming from `beforeEach` function => you are deploying each time a new contract and it throws, because you are creating your user only in the first test suite

Solutions:

1. Replace beforeEach with before
2. Create a user in each of your tests

Comment: can you please give suggestions how to check table data in test? Your answer solves the problem for deleting data but still gives error for ``it("Should check user", async ()``